# How do I set Wordpress Posts to be sub-posts of another Post?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, data-modeling, categories

I have X posts about various people. I want to have each person post have a subset of associated posts. Is there any way to do this?

I understand people could be categories, but then I run into a problem of not being able to allow for textual data associated with the people (categories don't have a post-page equivalent).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done with Wordpress *posts* because their `post_parent` field cannot be set using the Wordpress admin interface as it can for *pages*.

However, given that both content types use the same database table and share many fields, it should be possible to write a plugin to allow the `post_parent` field to be set for posts, you could then retrieve a post's child posts using the `get_children` function.

You'd need to add a metabox to the post edit page to provide a form for selecting the post parent, and then hook into the `save_post` action to save the chosen post to the `post_parent` field. See this example of how to add a metabox and hook into the `save_post` action: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Example

Answer (score 0):

Creating these relationships and displaying them on any desired page with a widget or shortcode can be easily done with a plugin called **Sub Posts**. It's not a free plugin, but it will do exactly what you're asking. You can find more information at www.subposts.com